# How to resolve Sequence contains more than one matching element issue in CLOSEDXML?

Tags: vb.net, closedxml

What I am doing is just saving an excel template without inserting any data...
This is my code below.

```
Dim wb As XLWorkbook
wb = New XLWorkbook(rawfilelocation)
wb.SaveAs(filelocation, True) '---- I even tried false
```

This error I am getting every time.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLDataValidations.ProcessRangeRemoved(IXLRange range)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLDataValidations.Delete(IXLDataValidation dataValidation)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLDataValidations.Consolidate()
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.GenerateWorksheetPartContent(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, XLWorksheet xlWorksheet, SaveOptions options, SaveContext context)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreateParts(SpreadsheetDocument document, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreatePackage(String filePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file, Boolean validate, Boolean evaluateFormulae)
   at nproject.frmReportPreview.ExcelSave(String ExcelFile, String Excelext) in D:\MainProject\nproject\nproject\frmReportPreview.vb:line 1312
```

I am even posting an excel template Dropbox link here

[Excel Template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jynokm6tm2vqo3d/GSTR1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the 5 MB file size limit. That's quite a big file given that it's supposedly only a template.

Comment: Its actually a government template with macros. We have to fill the amount in it and it calculates the stuff. I am sorry I didnt checked that. I re-upload it again

Comment: @FrancoisBotha Do download the file, Ssly the file is a headache...